# Prompt string PS4 duplicating itself when using set -x

Tags: bash, scripts, prompt, shebang

My OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

I use tracing for troubleshooting a script. I've notice different behaviors in the tracing depending on how I set it up. I would like to understand why it behaves this way.

I normally activate tracing using `set -x` in my script where I need the tracing to take place. However the Prompt String PS4 ("+ " by default) seems to "duplicate" itself.

[image]

If I active tracing in the shebang #! line, PS4 is only printed once.

[image]

Similarly, if I call `bash` directly for running my script, and specifying `-x` in the command line, PS4 is also only printed once.

[image]

Why is `set -x` behaving differently in the first example ? I guess there is something fundamental about the shell which I am not getting here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction here is not where you place the `-x`, it's whether you specify a shell to use (either via a shebang, or by invoking the script explicitly with `bash -x`).

According to `man bash`, `PS4`:

> ```
>    PS4    The value of this parameter is expanded  as  with  PS1  and  the
>           value  is  printed  before  each command bash displays during an
>           execution trace.  The first character of PS4 is replicated  mul‐
>           tiple  times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indi‐
>           rection.  The default is ``+ ''.
> ```

however it is not forthcoming about what *"levels of indirection"* means in this context.

When you try to execute a text file without specifying what interpreter to use, the system call to `execve` fails with `ENOEXEC (Exec format error)`. What happens next depends on the shell from which you are trying to execute it, as described here:

- [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373294/65304)

In particular, if the invoking shell is `bash`, then the script appears to get executed directly by the invoking shell: this appears to be the "indirection" mentioned in the manual:

```
$ strace -e trace=%process -f bash -c 'echo "Starting $0"; ./hw_no_shebang; echo "Finished."'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo \"Starting $0\"; ./hw_no_sheb"...], 0x7ffd3dadbee8 /* 25 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f95fe939740) = 0
Starting bash
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f95fe939a10) = 26515
strace: Process 26515 attached
[pid 26514] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26515] execve("./hw_no_shebang", ["./hw_no_shebang"], 0x555e5058a4f0 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
++ echo Hello
Hello
++ echo World
World
++ set +x
[pid 26515] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 26515] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 26515
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26515, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7fffba5272d0, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
Finished.
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Note that the `bash -c` in the strace call here takes the place of your interactive shell, rather than of the `bash -x` that you used in your last example.

As soon as we add a shebang, ex.:

```
$ cat hw_shebang
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "Hello"
echo "World"
set +x
```

then (regardless of whether `-x` is invoked using `set` or otherwise), then `execve` succeeds and the script is executed in its own shell, without "indirection":

```
$ strace -e trace=%process -f bash -c 'echo "Starting $0"; ./hw_shebang; echo "Finished."'
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo \"Starting $0\"; ./hw_shebang"...], 0x7ffccc0af338 /* 25 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f81b9ed2740) = 0
Starting bash
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f81b9ed2a10) = 26553
strace: Process 26553 attached
[pid 26552] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26553] execve("./hw_shebang", ["./hw_shebang"], 0x55879d9924f0 /* 25 vars */) = 0
[pid 26553] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa55de83740) = 0
+ echo Hello
Hello
+ echo World
World
+ set +x
[pid 26553] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 26553] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 26553
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26553, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
wait4(-1, 0x7ffda2983b10, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
Finished.
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

If you'd invoked the no-shebang script from `dash` for example, the behavior would be different: after the initial failed `execve`, it would have `execve`'d `/bin/sh` to execute the script:

```
$ strace -e trace=%process -f dash -c 'echo "Starting $0"; ./hw_no_shebang; echo "Finished."'
execve("/bin/dash", ["dash", "-c", "echo \"Starting $0\"; ./hw_no_sheb"...], 0x7ffc283d8638 /* 25 vars */) = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd2cc787540) = 0
Starting dash
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd2cc787810) = 26590
strace: Process 26590 attached
[pid 26589] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26590] execve("./hw_no_shebang", ["./hw_no_shebang"], 0x557143e3c8d8 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
[pid 26590] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "./hw_no_shebang"], 0x557143e3c8d8 /* 25 vars */) = 0
[pid 26590] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f3b9aa14540) = 0
+ echo Hello
Hello
+ echo World
World
[pid 26590] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 26590] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 26590
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=26590, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
Finished.
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```